Possibly abandoned child/teen with telekinetic abilities
So I've been looking for this movie for years. and i've had no luck, so maybe one of you guys can help.
I watched it with my sister, back in the early 90's. i would guess around '90/'91. (i was just young.)
It was on Cable TV. (I swear it was lifetime. but I could be wrong.)
It was about someone who was abandoned as a child, possibly given up for adoption. and as the movie went on, you found he had special abilities, I want to say he was able to move things with his mind, maybe. (I keep thinking when he did that, there were animated purple strands to illustrate it was him moving it. though That could just be my brain working overtime to try to remember it.) At the end of the film he got on a bus to find his parents. And he may of had a guitar with him, if i remember correctly.
Also I thought the movie was called: Chosen One, or The Chosen one. But after years of looking online, I haven't been able to find it at all.
Do you have any idea what move it is? 

http://jamesaconrad.com/TK/TK-movie-list.html

I wasn't able to find it there. But i did end up finding the movie it's: The Gifted One.  But thank you for trying to help. =]

you should answer the question, and accept it so that you we can close the question.

The Gifted One (1989), Made for TV Movie/Series Pilot that was never picked up.

A young boy can transfer his body energy into ESP and heal sick people. While the subject of scientists' studies, he runs away to try to find out about his past and why he is the way he is.


Can you link to any relevant information or footage? Or at least explain why you think this is the movie?

Well, he's the OP, so he would know. But Dev, it is recommended to at least add a link or a short synopsis and accept the answer to effectively close it.
